# pandas 2 pyarrow not converting date "10/18/2006"

Tags: pandas, pyarrow

just starting out with pandas 2 and wanted to use arrow backend but It's not converting a date field from the csv. On the csv date2 is in the format "10/18/2006"  is called date2. Why is this happening please AND how can I convert date2 into date32[day][pyarrow] format.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyarrow as pa

df_date_test = pd.read_csv( core_test , engine="pyarrow", dtype_backend="pyarrow")
```

versions

```
pandas version 2.1.1
numpy version 1.26.2
pyarrow version 14.0.1
```

the layout of df_date_test is

```
    name    date1   date2
0   bob     2007-01-03  10/18/2006
1   bob     2007-01-04  10/18/2007
2   bob     2007-01-05  10/18/2008
3   bob     2007-01-08  10/18/2009
```

with dtypes

```
name          string[pyarrow]
date1    date32[day][pyarrow]
date2         string[pyarrow]
dtype: object
```

```
from df_date_test = pd.read_csv( test_data , engine="pyarrow",dtype_backend="pyarrow")

 df_date_test.date1.dtypes is string[pyarrow]
 df_date_test.date1[0] is '10/18/2006' 


 <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
 RangeIndex: 504528 entries, 0 to 504527 Series name: date1 Non-Null Count Dtype -------------- ----- 341712

 non-null string[pyarrow]

 dtypes: string[pyarrow](1) memory usage:
```

Answer (score 0):

I think we can first read the CSV as a normal dataframe.(i assume core_test is a variable that holds file path)

```
df_date_test = pd.read_csv(core_test)
```

Then we can convert the datatime like you want

```
df_date_test['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df_date_test['date2'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

Now since we converted, we can use arrow for backend

```
pd.set_option('mode.use_arrow', True)
```

At the end we can convert df to PyArrow format

```
final_df = pa.Table.from_pandas(df_date_test)
```

Let's hope it will help. Hit me up if you encounter any problems. Good luck!

Comment: hi there @erogluegemen thanks for taking the time.  I got this error "OptionError: No such keys(s): 'mode.use_arrow'"  but progress :-) the date is in the right format. Something I can play with.  I was hoping that pyarrow would be able to handle this situation as I stipulate the engine in the 
df_date_test = pd.read_csv( core_test , engine="pyarrow", dtype_backend="pyarrow

Comment: Sorry, I'm familiar with that :(
Maybe this link can help you:
https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/pandas.html#datetime-timestamp-types
I can suggest you to check Datetime (Timestamp) types and Date types sections.
Best wishes!!!

Comment: will do and thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly specify the date format of each date/time columns with `parse_dates` and `date_format` argurments.

But then for some reason pandas assumes that date2 is of type `datetime64[ns]`, which needs to be explicitly converted back to `date32[day][pyarrow]` with the `dtype` argument.

```
date_format = {
    "date1": "%Y-%m-%d",
    "date2": "%m/%d/%Y",
}

pd.read_csv(
    "foo.csv" ,
    engine="pyarrow", 
    dtype_backend="pyarrow",
    parse_dates=list(date_format.keys()),
    date_format=date_format,
    dtype={"date2": "date32[day][pyarrow]"},
)
```

There are more options you can play with in the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Comment: no luck "ValueError: object of type <class 'str'> cannot be converted to int  "  I did read the docs but this is not sinking in.

Comment: it works for me, are you sure your data is correct? Are all columns correctly formed?

Comment: sorry I didn't thank you for taking an interest. I have updated the question with clarification of the data. I am pretty sure that it's correct and formatted correctly. what I am having trouble with is that arrow can't figure out that this is a date. It's formatted like a date and the name has date in it.